# Memory leak in Derby database while executing Timer task

Tags: java, memory-leaks, derby

I have strange situation. When executing this code, NetBeansIDE profiler shows memory leak (and after some time elapses, application quit because of insufficient memory):

```
public class SomeClass extends TimerTask {

    private static final Timer timer = new Timer();

    public SomeClass() {
        //Delay 0, repeat every 20ms
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(SomeClass.this, 0, 20);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try (Connection connDB = 
                 DriverManager.getConnection(
                         "jdbc:derby:someDataBase;create=true"); 
             Statement st = connDB.createStatement()) {
             //Some code in normal situation. But the problem
             //exists even without additional code..
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SomeClass.class.getName()).log(
                    Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the snapshots:
[image]
Memory (Heap)
[image]
Memory (GC) - Surviving generations
Is this some Derby database bug?
Running on `JDK8_u31`, Derby version/package: `db-derby-10.11.1.1-lib`.

**EDIT 1:**
When switched to `HSQLDB` database - no more memory leaks occurred while thousands of connections were opened and closed:
[image]
Wow! :)
[image]

Comment: You are closing the connection and the statement, but are you also using resultsets and closing them?

Comment: No, the code is exactly as you see, no `ResultSet` involved..

Comment: *"No, the code is exactly as you see"* - So ... what does "//some code" mean?  Are you really just creating and discarding connections and statement objects??

Comment: No code. Yes, only `Connection` and `Statement` opened and closed. I was surprised.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought that this might be due to `Statement` and/or `Connection` not implementing `AutoCloseable`.  However, according to the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3), that would be a compilation error ... and the javadocs say that those interfaces do implement it.

It looks like it is a Derby bug, and it might be related to this one:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-5415

Use the memory profiler to try to see what classes of object are leaking.  That should give you some more clues.

Comment: It seems that it could be true.. And bug is opened on 16/Sep/11, and still unresolved...

Comment: Note that the bug report offers a possible work-around.  Don't close the `Statement`.  Another one is to use a connection pool rather than repeatedly opening / closing connections.  If nothing else, it will be more efficient.

Comment: Yes, I've tried to open and close `Statement` and `ResultSet` many times, and it seems that `Memory (GC)` not rising anymore. But it's not very convenient and efficient to keep `Connection` always open, keeping in mind that loop could take long period of time. Another problem :)

Comment: I said connection pool, not "keep Connection always open".  And besides, keeping a connection open for a long time is very efficient.  Each time you open a connection you have the overheads of setting up a new Socket, establishing the network connection, doing the SSL negotiation, etc.

Comment: `Derby` - in trashcan. Tried with `H2` - the same problem. `HSQLDB` - the winner here :) Absolutely no problems and no leaks when opening and closing connections. And less RAM consumption. I tested with `2ms` loop - CPU load was at 50 -60 %. Will see later how `HSQLDB` will perform. At least now I'm happy :) I'm very surprised why `Derby` developers do nothing about it... It is very serious drawback.

Comment: I suspect it is because they think that people shouldn't be writing applications that churning the connections like that.  Don't you find it interesting that 2 different products have the same "bug" and won't fix it?

Comment: Yes, maybe they share some code ideas.. My impression is that they have written the application and haven't done any profiling.. I think even one connection, which is closed with even minimal memory leak is serious problem, huge error. Also I noticed in `Derby` big memory leaks with `CLOB` data type, so had to switch to store big data in files, rather than in DB.

Comment: As the Derby developer explained: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-5415?focusedCommentId=13135989&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-13135989 "There's no OutOfMemoryError, even with a small heap, so it doesn't look like a memory leak". So maybe your problem is different.

Comment: I don't think so. Try to experiment (try to open connection and close thousands of times). Here `PreparedStatement` is not involved. So I suppose `PreparedStatement` in Derby also has suspicious memory leaks... Not good.

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis - If you think this is "not good" ..... raise a bug report.  If you want it fixed ..... raise a bug report.  Otherwise, change your code so that you don't churn the connections.

Comment: But the bug is already raised from16/Sep/11, and nothing was done up to now. Switched completely to `HSQLDB`.

Comment: Raise it again.  We think it isn't the same bug.  Yours is apparently causing hard OOMEs, where the other one wasn't.